# Using urlencode() in form

Tags: php, html, urlencode, urldecode

I need to send special characters (like polish characters) using form. I figured out i need to use urlencode and urldecode. How to use it when sending form?

The code of form is

```
<form id="form1" action="add.php" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
  Description: <input type=text name="title" maxlenght=150/><br/>
  Link: <input type=text name="link"/><br/>
<input type=submit value="Send"/>
```

Comment: Sidenote: Typo "maxlenght". Switch the "h" with the "t" ;)

Comment: Please [learn to love labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks. I didn't see that.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks for advice. I'm a beginner, i'll read that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to use them at all.

Submitting a form will cause the browser to encode characters automatically.

Since you are using PHP, `$_POST` will be populated with decoded characters automatically.

---

If you are having character encoding issues where the characters are being encoded or decoded incorrectly, then see [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through).

Comment: Thanks. My problem was using mysqli. I tried with PDO and it works.